# How to interpret service fabric status when stuck deployment at last node

Tags: azure-service-fabric

when we are deploying in Azure service fabric the Rolling forward is stuck in node 5 with warning. Does this mean first 4 nodes it deployed without error and there is an issue with 5th node? Is this representing this wrongly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means the upgrade on **upgrade domain** (not a node)'*' is in the progress. But if it is taking longer then expected this is most likely an error. The rest 4 nodes are fine and already upgraded.

Powershell equivalent of the information you are seeing in the cluster explorer is `Get-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName fabric:/xxx`. This command should give you a little bit more information what is actually happening.

About dealing with these kind of issues, it is hard to tell what actually went wrong. Usually those upgrade issues come in pair with some errors in the cluster that should give more insight. Nevertheless you can always try to request an upgrade rollback, restart a node or even delete an application and redeploy it. It always depends on which action you can afford.

> '*' *I said upgrade domain, because upgrade domains can contain more
>   than one node. In your case probably node equals upgrade domain. But
>   you can have for example 3 upgrade domains and 5 nodes. At one time
>   only one upgrade domain is being updated, this way you can guarantee
>   that application is always running (even during an upgrade).*